# How to execute bash/shell script in Linux from an Oracle DBMS_Scheduler?

Tags: bash, oracle, plsql, execute

I have a Linux Oracle Server. The database is generating CSV files with a custom stored procedure, now at the end of this procedure. I want to execute a bash/shell script in linux to push this files to Amazon S3 Bucket.

I am getting errors trying to schedule the process in oracle:

EXTERNAL_LOG_ID="job_2369137_852690",
ORA-27369: job of type EXECUTABLE failed with exit code: Argument list too long

Using DBM_SCHEDULER to create a JOB type Sript, External

```
#!/bin/bash
echo hello world

DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
job_name => '"ODSMGR"."TEST_JOB"',
job_type => 'EXTERNAL_SCRIPT',
job_action => '#!/bin/bash
echo hello world',
number_of_arguments => 0,
start_date => NULL,
repeat_interval => NULL,
end_date => NULL,
enabled => FALSE,
auto_drop => FALSE,
comments => '');
```

Comment: Now i am getting this error:
ORA-27369: job of type EXECUTABLE failed with exit code: 7

Answer (score 1):

The `DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB` you are using has incorrect arguments. You should preferably follow these standard steps for running a program.

First create a program with appropriate name and define what to run. In the below example I'm running a `bash` command directly, You may put them into a separate shell script with relevant permissions and add its name under `program_action`

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_PROGRAM (
 program_name=> 'COPY_PROGRAM',
 program_type=> 'EXECUTABLE',
 program_action  => '/bin/bash -c "echo hello world"',
 enabled=> TRUE,
 comments=> 'Push files to Amazon S3 Bucket.'
);
END;
/
```

Then, create the job using that program.

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name     => 'TEST_JOB',
   program_name => 'COPY_PROGRAM',
   start_date => NULL,
   repeat_interval => NULL,
   end_date => NULL,
   enabled => FALSE,
   auto_drop => FALSE,
   comments => '');
END;
/
```

Refer [this](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/scheduler-10g) link for more details.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. I did the same as your example and I am getting this error code:
"ORA-27369: job of type EXECUTABLE failed with exit code: No such file or directory
"

Comment: What about the credentials? This is a linux server in the Amazon cloud and we are not using password, Do I need to send login credentials?

Comment: @JorgeFlores :Check your bash path, it should be somewhere else ( not in `/bin/bash`) . Regarding your question about Amazon cloud, I'm not sure and that's beyond the scope of this question. You should consider asking a new one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.